# login_url filter creates permanent wp-admin -> wp-login redirection loop

Tags: filters, login

I have created a custom login page on my site and used the login_url filter to redirect to that page each time there's a request. The filter looks like:

```
// Login page
function my_login_page($login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth) {
    // This will append /custom-login/ to you main site URL as configured in general settings (ie https://domain.com/custom-login/)
    $login_url = site_url( '/acceder/', 'login' );
    if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect ), $login_url );
    }
    if ( $force_reauth ) {
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'reauth', '1', $login_url );
    }
    return $login_url;
}
add_filter('login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 3);
```

The problem is that since then everytime I login with my account and try to access the dashboard I can't. Whether I am logged-in or not logged-in I get to my custom login page.

Is there a way to solve this problem? So far I tried:

- Remove .htaccess and restore it.
- Flush wp rewrite rules.
- Deactivate all plugins.
- Remove all functions that may create a redirection loop and
  activate one by one until I found it.

Comment: Your code seems fine, so it's probably a *theme* issue. Try switching to a default theme and try that code as a Must-Use plugin.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ I am trying to find out what theme issue it might be commenting all the functions and uncommenting one by one. In my development environment using Valet on Mac OS it works fine, on my staging environment which is the same as production is where the problem appears. Do you know what kind of functions or code might cause that issue?

Comment: Could be a redirection function, which could be in PHP or JS. (Or although unlikely, there might be a `meta` redirect somewhere...) If you want to be sure, try using a different page as the login page - just change the `site_url( '/acceder/', 'login' )` to a dummy URL... But are you sure this is not a caching issue?

Comment: I mean, if the dummy URL does not work, then there might be another code that's altering the login URL.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ I couldn't find the error yet, I will keep looking for it.